# Access local scope variable inside template as a variable instead of string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive where I have a scope(local) with a variable `type` and with that value I should return the appropriate template. `chooseTemplateByType` returns a string with the appropriate template based on that `type` which could be a `text_field` for example.

```
template:
  chooseTemplateByType(type)
```

The question is how to access that variable type of my local scope so I can pass the value into my function `chooseTemplateByType`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Is the title, gonna put on question also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to pass the `type` variable to your directive via an attribute.

HTML

```
<my-directive type="foo"></my-directive>
```

JS

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: function(elem, attr){
      return "<h1>" + attr.type + "</h1>"; // will output <h1>foo</h1>
    }
  };
});
```

OR

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
      return attr.type + '.html'; // will load foo.html
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I'm using just template, instead templateUrl, elem and attr are still available ?

Comment: Thanks, that is correct. Although I got a problem where my function is not being called with the right value. I believe is because the page is load but the values are not there yet. Tried to use $timeout but it didn't work and since I need to call ```chooseTemplateByType``` every time the user change a value in a select field also is breaking. But this is enough to another question if I don't find a solution. But if anyone had a problem like this, be free to send a link, would be great help.